# Which statistical test to use for my data

Tags: anova

My question is whether a low calorie diet with prescribed exercise is more effective than a low calorie diet without prescribed exercise for weight loss

study design: randomised study of 2 parallel intervention groups with 30 participants. intervention required both groups to only eat a low calorie diet provided to them for 12 weeks. The exercise diet group were prescribed 30 minutes of exercise. Assessments were performed at baseline, 6 weeks, 12 weeks and 24 weeks (follow up). primary outcome measure is BMI.

What statistical test should I use in SPSS and do i compare the baseline with the rest of the data or do i consider the means of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a control group, your inference is limited by all forms of Hawthorne effect. If the design is balanced, consider fitting a mixed model with random effects for participant and time. Transform follow-up data to a wide format, as baseline values do not randomly vary by experimental design, and either adjust for baseline BMI as a covariate or as an offset (equivalent to t-test for paired differences but with multiple outcomes).